# Linear Algebra Done Right: Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

I understand how in 1.23 Axler states that F<sup>s</sup> is the set of all functions that map from the set S to F.

He later states that we can think of F<sup>n</sup>  as F<sup>{1,2,3,....,n}</sup>

Although an explanation in the book is provided, I'm still confused as to how we can represent it that way.

For example, according to the previous statement, R<sup>4</sup> can be written as R<sup>{1,2,3,4}</sup>. However wouldn't that say R<sup>4</sup> is the set of all functions that map from {1,2,3,4} to a real number R? Wouldn't R<sup>4</sup> just be the all the sets that have 4 elements from R or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: In standard notation, $$\mathbb{R}^4 = \{ (a,b,c,d) : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ Can you see how this bijects naturally with the functions $\{1,2,3,4\} \to \mathbb{R}$? For culture, the notation originates with combinatorics, as the number of functions $F \to G$ for finite sets $F,G$ is precisely $|G|^{|F|}$.

Comment: Not quite sure that I am understanding your confusion, but (much as William is doing), write $S=\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$. Suppose that $f$ is a real valued function on $S$. Then one gets an element of ${\mathbb R}^4$ by $(f(1), f(2), f(3),  f(4) )$. Conversely, given an element $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in {\mathbb R}^4$ one gets a real valued function $f$ on $S$ by the recipe $f(k) = x_k$  . Hope that helps!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^4$ is not the set of all sets that contain $4$ elements from $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, $\{1,5,10,12\}=\{12,5,1,10\}$, but for elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$, $(1,5,10,12)\ne (12,5,1,10)$. The distinction is that in sets order of elements make no difference, but elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$ are $4$-tuples where order matters.

An $n$-tuple can be thought of as a function that maps each index $i=1~..~n$ to its corresponding value. For instance $(1,5,10,12)$ can be thought of as the function $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$1\mapsto 1,~~2\mapsto 5,~~3\mapsto 10,~~4\mapsto 12.$$

Comment: Ah I see my misunderstanding. Thank you! I was somewhat confused as R^{1,2,3,4} would be a set of functions no? Or do I just consider 1 function from that set?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}^{\{1,2,3,4\}}$ would be the set of all functions from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Any specific element of $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be thought of as a single function, and the whole of $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be thought of as the set of all such functions, just the same way as we think of it as the set of all possible $4$-tuples.

(Keep in mind that in practice you probably want to keep thinking of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as the set of all $4$-tuples. When one imagines an element of $\mathbb{R}^4$ one usually imagines a $4$-tuple, not a function. Of course, the two views are equivalent.)